# Touchpad not working ! I have updated the GRUB and my xlist does show the synaptic drive but still my touchpad is not working!

Tags: grub2, touchpad, synaptics, ubuntu-drivers, xorg.conf

I have dell Inspiron 3000 series and Ubuntu 18.04. Recently my touchpad stopped working. It used to work fine but just a couple of days before, it has stopped working. I don't think this is a hardware problem because neither my laptop fell nor it was rudely handled. I had a few small updates (which are notified almost every week), my laptop notified me off and I updated it. But now the touchpad is not working.

I want to notify you that:

I tried looking for the solution on the internet and tried updating the grub file. `egrep -i 'synap' /proc/bus/input/devices` shows that the `Synaptics TM3096-006` driver is present. `lsmod` shows `psmouse` is used by `0`.

If a connect a dongle of an external mouse and try to move the cursor, it works, but the touchpad is still not working.

I just have Ubuntu as an OS. No other OS is present on my computer.

I haven't recently shifted to 18.04, It has been almost a year on this version.

This has never happened before and I am so frustrated. Please help!

Comment: Boot with a previous kernel. It is a bug with the latest 4.15.0-72 kernel.

Comment: yeah, that is my kernel. Could you tell me how do I remove the current version and boot with previous version

Comment: You can boot with a previous one using grub menu. An alternative is to upgrade to the HWE kernel. I think there is no bug there.

Comment: Somehow I am not able to access my GRUB menu. Whenever I press shift after the BIOS, the computer shows up the Ubuntu logo a little late but the GRUB menu never appears! I tried modifying GRUB file (HIDDEN_TIMEOUT value) but the same thing happens.
Can you tell me any other way I can change my kernel version to the previous one?

Comment: Did you update grub after changed the hidden timeout?

Comment: Yeah, that was the mistake I was making. My touchpad works now. Thank you.